# Using multiple branches of git notes

Tags: git

I am looking to use `git notes` to store benchmarking data of commits so I can maintain a history of a project's performance.

I know I can use `git notes` to attach metadata to commits, but I would like to store the benchmarking data in a separate branch other than `refs/notes/commits`, something like `refs/notes/benchmarks`, but I don't know how I would go about this.

Is it possible to use `git notes` in this way that I can have multiple branches of notes that refer to commits in `master`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like this:

```
git notes --ref refs/notes/benchmarks add [ -m 'msg' ]
```

You can then see your notes in `git log`

```
git log --notes=refs/notes/benchmarks
```

or read notes contents for particular object (e.g. commit -- but notes can annotate other kinds of objects as well, e.g. commit's tree)

```
git notes --ref refs/notes/benchmarks show <commit>
```